# Fatal error: Python-h not found on griddb python client

Tags: griddb

I installed my python client by running this on my centOS terminal:

```
$ wget \ https://github.com/griddb/python_client/archive/0.8.1.tar.gz
```

and unzipped it with this line of code:

```
tar xvzf 0.8.1.tar.gz
```

I also installed the necessary prerequisite files:

Swig:

```
$ wget https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/swig/swig-3.0.12.tar.gz
tar xvfz swig-3.0.12.tar.gz
cd swig-3.0.12
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Pcre:

```
$ sudo yum install pcre2-devel.x86_64
```

However, when I ran make in my python client directory:

```
make
```

I got an error:

fatal error: python.h: No such file or directory

Please, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix the error!
Apparently I installed the wrong python client, I git cloned the right python client with this command

```
git clone https://github.com/griddb/python_client.git
```

check out the full documentation on griddb python client installation here:
https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-rpmyum/#install-with-rpm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).